# Querying with comparison of multiple relationships in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a structure like this:

A **Position** has_many **Requests**
A **Request** belongs_to a **User**
A **Group** has_many **:members**, through: :memberships, source: :user

I would like to get all groups where not all members has a particular request.

**UPDATE**: I have a form were I can search for individual users and groups.
I can click a user and send him/her a request (and by that, create a request).
I can also click a group and send every user in that group a request in the same manner.

The position has multiple requests, and one request has one user.

As you can see, I can make sure that no user, having a request to a given position is shown in the search result.
*Bottom line: If every member in a group has a request to a given position, the group should not appear in the search result. If not all members of that group has a request, the group should be shown.*

Right now I manage to get individual users that doesn't belong to the request:

```
@users = User.search(query_str).where.not(id: @position.requests)
```

I'm trying to do something like

```
@groups = Group.search(query_str).where.not(
            @position.request.include?(all users of a Group))
```

I made a method in `Position < ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
def user_exists?(user)
    # Check if user exists in position
    self.requests.map(&:user_id).include?(user.id)
end

def all_users_exists?(users)
    users.each do |user|
      unless self.user_exists? user
        return false
      end
    end
  true
end
```

The way I can come up with to filter out groups using this method is in the views when iterating over all groups, which feels like a terrible solution.

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
    <% unless @position.all_users_exists? group.members %>
         # Print list-item...
```

Could anyone please help me filtering out the groups with all members in a request when querying instead?

Oh, and I'm using rails 4.2.5

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be clearer about your final goal? Don't quite understand "all groups where not all members has a particular request". Maybe provide an example if possible? It seems like you are looking for something along the lines of User.joins(...).search(...).where("...", @position), but I'm just not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: It seems like you are looking for something along the lines of User.joins(members: :requests).search(...).where("...", @position), but I'm just not sure what you are trying to achieve. Note the nested join "members: :requests)". Check in the console what query it generates.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Mingsheng. Sorry if the question was unclear, I have updated it with a clarification.